# how to display string array?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, string, jlist

I want to display an array list in a JList. I have a method that accepts this string...not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 1):

`JList` provides a constructor `JList(Object[])` which you can call after unpacking your `ArrayList<String>` using `toArray()`

```
list = new JList(arr.toArray())
```